# How to test dependencies, added via addDependency?

Tags: testing, webpack

I'm trying to test that loader has add dependencies via [`loaderContext.addDependency`](https://webpack.js.org/api/loaders/#thisadddependency), but stats output seems din't contain any trace of dependencies, that was added via method above.

Command to get stats is:

```
webpack --profile --json > stats.json
```

or [`toJson()`](https://webpack.js.org/api/node/#statstojsonoptions) via API